# How to restrict Android Market search results to a particular publisher?

Tags: google-play-store, search

Is there any way that I can restrict searches in the Android Market to just show apps from one particular publisher?  For example, if I wanted to just see apps from Google, searching for "Google Inc." will also show apps that mention "Google Inc." in their descriptions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there is an app you like by that publisher, open the entry for the app in the market and select "View more applications".

OR

You can search by name:

```
pub:"Google Inc."
```